# For loop not working?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I wrote this function for my C++ class and I have tried x <= 4 and also tried x >= 4, but when I did trace on it I don't see it looping like it should.  What it does is takes an array of 5 numbers and sorts them, then checks to see if the combination makes a full house.

```
bool isFullHouse(int)
    {
        int match = 0;
        BubbleSort(DiceHeld, 5);
        for ( int x=0; x <= 4; x++ )
        {
            if (((DiceHeld[1] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[2] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[3] == x+2) && (DiceHeld[4] == x+2) && (DiceHeld[5] == x+2)) ||
                ((DiceHeld[1] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[2] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[3] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[4] == x+2) && (DiceHeld[5] == x+2)) ||
                ((DiceHeld[1] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[2] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[3] == x+3) && (DiceHeld[4] == x+3) && (DiceHeld[5] == x+3)) ||
                ((DiceHeld[1] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[2] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[3] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[4] == x+3) && (DiceHeld[5] == x+3)) ||
                ((DiceHeld[1] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[2] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[3] == x+4) && (DiceHeld[4] == x+4) && (DiceHeld[5] == x+4)) ||
                ((DiceHeld[1] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[2] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[3] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[4] == x+4) && (DiceHeld[5] == x+4)) ||
                ((DiceHeld[1] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[2] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[3] == x+5) && (DiceHeld[4] == x+5) && (DiceHeld[5] == x+5)) ||
                ((DiceHeld[1] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[2] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[3] == x+6) && (DiceHeld[4] == x+2) && (DiceHeld[5] == x+2)) ||
                ((DiceHeld[1] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[2] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[3] == x+6) && (DiceHeld[4] == x+6) && (DiceHeld[5] == x+6)) ||
                ((DiceHeld[1] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[2] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[3] == x+1) && (DiceHeld[4] == x+6) && (DiceHeld[5] == x+6)))
            {
                match = 1;
            }
        }
        if (match == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not *looping like it should*? How is it looping differently to what you expected?

Comment: I can't comment on the *contents* of that loop -- oy -- but the loop itself looks fine, and should iterate five times.

Comment: the for-loop itself looks fine to me. for(int x = 0; x <= 4; x++){} is valid. I would expect x to be 0, 1, 2, 3, then 4 before leaving the loop.

Comment: By fullhouse you mean what exactly? Poker style full house?

Comment: Are you sure you got indexes right? You said you have array of 5 numbers, yet you are using DiceHeld[5] which is sixth element of an array.

Comment: Please tag homework questions as such...

Comment: Yes , poker full house xx yyy or xxx yy, In trace it hits the If in the For-loop and the next thing it does is check the if for match == 1

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations by any chance? I can easily see the `match == 1` test getting optimized to a `break` so that it stops early...

Comment: It's much more straightforward to count how many of each number appears, and then you can check that some number appears twice and some other number appears 3 times. Equivalently, you can check that every number appears 0, 2 or 3 times or that no number appears 1, 4 or 5 times.

Comment: Thanks, the issue turned out to be that in my function isFullHouse(int)  was wrong so the array I passed never made it.  The second issue was I started with 1 and not 0, thanks Almo and Mrpyo.  Also i didn't know there was a TAG for Home Work Sorry.

Comment: All though this was closed by casperOne 4 hours ago as "being ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered" it was answered yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fun, here's a version that doesn't require such heavy if logic or sorting:

```
static const int kNumDice = 5;

bool isFullHouse()
{
    // There are only 2 possible patterns for full house on a set of numbers, sorted or not
    // Either the first 3 dice have the same value and the 4th and 5th dice are the same
    // or the first 2 dice match and the 3rd, 4th, 5th dice match 

    int currentMatch = DiceHeld[0];
    int uniqueValues = 1;
    int matchLength = 1;

    for(int i=1; i<kNumDice; i++)
    {
        // Start next match
        if(DiceHeld[i] != currentMatch)
        {
            if(matchLength < 2)
            {
                return false; 
            }

            if(++uniqueValues > 2)
            {
                return false;
            }

            currentMatch = DiceHeld[i];
            matchLength = 1;
        }
        else if(++matchLength > 3)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your indices of `DiceHeld` should probably run from 0 to 4. Depending on your compiler and debugger, a memory error might not be apparent, but still occurring.

I also bet that `match` is not 1 after exiting the loop.